# How to install Qbittorrent in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qbittorrent

I did what the site says :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

Then I get the error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qbittorrent : Depends: libqt5xml5 (>= 5.9.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Site? Which site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) as I can't reproduce on fresh on 20.04 LTS VM with only qbittorrent PPA added.

Comment: Their site, qbittorrent site.

Comment: libqt5xml5 : Ubuntu 18.04 only https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libqt5xml5&searchon=names

Comment: I'm on 20.04, thank you.

Comment: The package is available without adding any PPAs - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qbittorrent ; it's a community package so you only need to enable 'universe' - is that your issue?  You're not sure how to enable universe?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, that was my issue not enabling the options in "downloadable from the internet".

Comment: See [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for).  PPA is an avenue of last resort.  If a package is already in repos, it's not a good idea to add a PPA unless you need a specific package version provided by the PPA.  Even then, conflicting dependencies can break your system.  Best to stick with the software in repos when it's available.